# rails spree has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, spree

'm trying to tweek Spree to my needs and I've hit a bump. I'll try to explain as best as I can without pasting too much code, 'cause Spree has quite a lot of it...

For starters. I've extended `OptionType` like this

```
Spree::OptionType.class_eval do
  PRODUCT_TYPES = SuperMap.new( [:default, 0],
                            [:vehicle_bonnet, 1],
                            [:vehicle_images, 2])

  super_mapped_attr :product_type, PRODUCT_TYPES

  attr_accessible :product_type
end
```

I want to check in the `show` view of the `ProductsController` what sort of `product_type` I'm dealing with, like this:

```
<% if @product.option_types.product_type_key == :vehicle_bonnet %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

and I get ``` undefined method  ``product_type_key' ```. This method should be available thanks to `SuperMap`.
Now, the `Product` and `OptionType` has a bit strange association (for me at least).

```
module Spree
  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :product_option_types, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :option_types, :through => :product_option_types
  end
end
```

so far seems to be ok.

```
module Spree
  class ProductOptionType < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :option_type
    acts_as_list :scope => :product
  end
end
```

and now comes the weird part:

```
module Spree
  class OptionType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :option_values, :order => :position, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :product_option_types, :dependent => :destroy
    has_and_belongs_to_many :prototypes, :join_table => 'spree_option_types_prototypes'

    attr_accessible :name, :presentation, :option_values_attributes

    validates :name, :presentation, :presence => true
    default_scope :order => "#{self.table_name}.position"

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :option_values, :reject_if => lambda { |ov| ov[:name].blank? || ov[:presentation].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  end
end
```

this is actually the whole `OptionType` model. What suprises me it doesn't have `has_many :products, through: :product_option_types`. I've tried to add this line to my extension, but didn't help. I've tried few other thing of course, but it just made such a mess I went back to this version, since I think it shows best what I'm trying to achieve. What am I missing?

EDIT (solved, I should hope so...):

Turned out that in the `Product` model there was an alias `alias :options :product_option_types`, which was (imho) in the wrong place, because somewhere in the middle of a quite a long model (I should think it should have been somewhere closer to the `has_many`, but that's just me).

Further more, the `options` turned out to be an array, no that shocking come to think of it. So, what I did is extended the product model, added a method, where I'm checking the `product_type_key`, like so:

```
def type_of_product?(type)
  options.each do |opts| 
    if opts.option_type.product_type_key == type
      return true
    end
  end
  false
end
```

Not the prettiest method, but it works as I expect it to...